# Decoding html tags using json_decode() function

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to decode a JSON string using json_decode() in PHP. Part of my JSON string has HTML tags in it. Eg. (For better view of the code go to http://gist.github.com/605906)

```
$json = '{"productid" : "prod:a8f2d4ef-108e-5fbf-fa74-595ddc0c7950","memo" : "<div style=\"color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; background-image: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-color: #ffffff; background-position: initial initial; margin: 8px;\">WS1CI metered clack valve, 1\" for softener  P/N: V1CIDME-03</div>"}';
```

**But I am getting NULL values, when I do**

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

or

```
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$json = '{"productid" : "prod:a8f2d4ef-108e-5fbf-fa74-595ddc0c7950","memo" : "&lt;div style=\"color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; background-image: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-color: #ffffff; background-position: initial initial; margin: 8px;\"&gt;WS1CI metered clack valve, 1\" for softener  P/N: V1CIDME-03&lt;/div&gt;"}';


var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

You need to transform all html (like `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;`)

Comment: This does not answer the question. What happens is, the result of `print_r` is interpreted by the browser as HTML, so the result *seems* to be empty, but the JSON-decoded object still contains the correct string, that simply happens to be a bit of HTML that does not display anything. Your answer would allow to let the browser display the actual HTML code, but trying to use the HTML-escaped string for other purposes (creating a DOM element for instance) would probably not yield the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me. If you get a specific error check your PHP installation, but As of PHP 5.2.0 Json comes by default.

```
object(stdClass)#99 (2) {
  ["productid"]=>
  string(41) "prod:a8f2d4ef-108e-5fbf-fa74-595ddc0c7950"
  ["memo"]=>
  string(59) "WS1CI metered clack valve, 1" for softener  P/N: V1CIDME-03"
}
array(2) {
  ["productid"]=>
  string(41) "prod:a8f2d4ef-108e-5fbf-fa74-595ddc0c7950"
  ["memo"]=>
  string(59) "WS1CI metered clack valve, 1" for softener  P/N: V1CIDME-03"
}
```

Works even for the html.

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["productid"]=>
  string(41) "prod:a8f2d4ef-108e-5fbf-fa74-595ddc0c7950"
  ["memo"]=>
  string(328) "<div style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; background-image: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-color: #ffffff; background-position: initial initial; margin: 8px;">WS1CI metered clack valve, 1" for softener  P/N: V1CIDME-03</div>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your server's error_log. This might yield to some more information.