# php json_decode removing html tags

Tags: php, json

I am using php json_decode to parse API response and then json_encode to send response to client.

In a third party API call I am getting JSON response in which there is a key with value having html tags and html contents. When I print that data I can see those tags, but after json_decode, I can not see those tags, so that I am unable to keep those tags intact. I want that html content to go to database as it is [without any change at all].

`$result = curlGetWithHeaders("API URL", "Parameters for that URL");`

`$data = json_decode($result);`

So in `$result` I can see html tags but not in `$data`. 
And `var_dump($data)` says that it is `string`.

Response is = 
`{"array":{"id":1,"title":"Title","short_title":"abcd","description":"<ul><li>0</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li>"}}`

and after using `json_decode` I am getting description as pasred html.

`deals] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [deal] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [title] => title
                            [short_title] => abcd
                            [description] => 0
• A
• B
• C`

Comment: near duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837435/decoding-html-tags-using-json-decode-function). The selected answer there not so stellar though, IMHO.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it means I should use `str_replace` to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`

Comment: Can you show an example of what happens?

Comment: The title says the question is about `json_encode` but only `json_decode` is asked about. Which is it now?

Comment: apologies for all. code added, subject changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using `print_r` to display the contents of your JSON-decoded object, what you see in your browser is something like that:

**stdClass Object ( [array] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [title] => Title [short_title] => abcd [description] =>**

- **0**
- **A**
- **B**
- **C**
- **D**

However, the effective contents of your object (without the browser interpreting the HTML tags) is this:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [array] => stdClass Object
    (
      [id] => 1
      [title] => Title
      [short_title] => abcd
      [description] => <ul><li>0</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li>
    )
)
```

You can see it clearly if you ask your browser to display the source of the page.

Your `description` field contains a plain string that happens to be HTML, that's all.

If you want to store the JSON-decoded data in your database without any modification, well, ***don't do anything*** and you'll get exactly what you want.

Now if you want to display the actual HTML code in your browser, you will have to escape the HTML special characters, like so:

```
echo htmlentities (print_r (json_decode ($json), true));
```

Note that you should get the `print_r` result first, and only then escape the HTML.

Comment: Your spot on about this. However I wonder how he outputted `$result` without the browser parsing the HTML?

Comment: As long as the HTML tags are inside a quoted string, they are not interpreted, so a `print_r` of the JSON data would display the (quoted) HTML code without the browser interpreting it.

Comment: I am looking into `network` request responses for now, using chrome.

Comment: @kuroineko : I can see tags in string format when printed before json_decode.

Comment: Well yes, isn't that how it should be? :)

Comment: @kuroineko : i amight be asking useless things but - i am getting `&acirc;�&cent;`. Exactly what I want to do - I want to give that string with html tags to front end as it is.

Comment: @Pranav This is exactly what your doing. Your sending HTML to the browser and the browser interprets it and displays it.

Comment: @Pranav Frankly I can't think of a way to be more explicit. Maybe I failed to decode your question, though.

Comment: @kuroineko : no, you did answered correctly, but I am still trying to get the required result. trying out solutions mentioned here.

Comment: @Pranav You said you wanted to store the returned API data raw in the database without any modification. Well don't to anything and you will get exactly that. If you want to display the HTML to the user without the browser intercepting and parsing it then you will have to encode it before outputting to the browser.

Comment: @kuroineko : yeah, first to DB and then to front end.. Thanks for all. ! thanks for your time.

Comment: @user555 Well put, mister. I'll add that to my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @kuroineko I don't mind at all, SO is like a wiki after all. Still kind wrap my head around how "HTML tags inside a quoted string" would make the browser not parse them.

Comment: @user555 Forget about it, I must have been delirious when I wrote that :D. The reason is different, but I'm a bit tired of this topic so I'll pass on a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but...

```
$p = '<p> This is some text</p>';

$j = json_encode(urlencode($p));

print_r($j);

echo '<br>';

$jd = json_decode(urldecode($j));

print_r($jd);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `htmlspecialchars()` function to encode the data first

and use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function to get back the result

```
$result = htmlspecialchars({"array":{"id":1,"title":"Title","short_title":"abcd","description":"<ul><li>0</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li>"}});
```

use it and when want back the html content

`htmlspecialchars_decode()` to get the html content back

Comment: thanks for response, But I get data in API response, so I need to json_decode it first. after `htmlspecialchars` unable to decode to json as it replaced even `double quotes`.

Comment: ENT_NOQUOTES use this flag

Comment: htmlentities($result, ENT_NOQUOTES);

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = '{"array":{"id":1,"title":"Title","short_title":"abcd","description":"<ul><li>0</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li>"}}';
$data = json_decode($result);
print "<pre>";
print_r($data);
print "</pre>";
```

Here your json string already got converted in array where "description" is having html tags included. with **print_r** you will bot able to see html tags as it gets interpreted by browser and you will see result that html will generate.

Now, if you want to shoe text with HTML you can use **htmlentities** like shown below.

```
print htmlentities($data->array->description);
```

**Output:**

```
<ul><li>0</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li>
```

Comment: ... or you could simply display the page source code. Saves a bit of typing :).

Comment: @kuroineko Or even better Xdebug together with `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to my question but it may help someone, whatever I was storing in DB was perfect. Problem was while displaying it. So now I could do it with `<pre></pre>` tags which will format the data while displaying. It just worked for me.